# SFTP on Raspberry Pi troubleshooting

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm trying to create a folder shared with SFTP in my Raspi. There are some issues, which are reported to be related to folder administration rights. Trying to solve them seems useless. I'm reporting everything so you can emulate the issue.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` i've put:
where the group **nas** contains the user **nasaccess**

```
SubSystem nas internal-sftp
Match Group nas
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

then

```
sudo groupadd nas
sudo gpasswd -a nasaccess nas
```

and making the chrooting:

```
sudo chown root:nasaccess /home/nasaccess
sudo chmod 750 /home/nasaccess
```

and added a folder inside:

```
sudo mkdir /home/nasaccess/files
sudo chown nasaccess: /home/nasaccess/files
sudo chmod 750 /home/nasaccess/files
```

restarted the ssh service, when connecting with nasaccess, I get:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe                                                                                               
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

The users which are not belonging to **nas** have full SFTP access, as expected. Why? The troubleshooting found searching randomly seems to now work.

The vorbose mode provides this:

```
sudo sftp -vvv nasaccess@localhost
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debia                 n-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "localhost" from file "/root/.ss                 h/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@open                 ssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@op                 enssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp                 521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diff                 ie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-n                 istp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2                 -nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,s                 sh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openss                 h.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12                 8,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rij                 ndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12                 8,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rij                 ndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,                 hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@op                 enssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,                 hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@op                 enssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp                 521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diff                 ie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12                 8,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rij                 ndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12                 8,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rij                 ndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,                 hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@op                 enssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,                 hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@op                 enssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 50:ed:ea:a5:d5:7a:5a:f0:ab:09:d6:e4:e4:e9:7c:d3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "localhost" from file "/root/.ss                 h/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,pa                 ssword
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
nasaccess@localhost's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 63 padlen 17 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Write failed: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for the `Subsystem` keyword is wrong. Try this instead:

```
Subsystem internal-sftp

Match Group nas
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

If you take a look at `/var/log/auth.log` on your server (yes, I know that's `localhost` in your case) you will see messages like this:

```
Jul  7 22:46:24 localhost sshd[30701]: Accepted publickey for jsmith from 192.168.56.1 port 61983 ssh2: RSA 86:87:b7:08:15:5e:a4:7b:32:ba:c8:fa:84:89:45:4c
Jul  7 22:46:24 localhost sshd[30701]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jsmith by (uid=0)
Jul  7 22:46:25 localhost sshd[30706]: subsystem request for sftp by user jsmith failed, subsystem not found
Jul  7 22:46:25 localhost sshd[30701]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user jsmith
```

The key here is the penultimate line, *subsystem request for sftp by user jsmith failed, subsystem not found*, which indicates something wrong with the subsystem command. Looking in the [man page for sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) could then lead you to the right syntax.

Comment: I would say that doesn't work. Mainly because without the "nas" after SubSystem says that a command is missing. I tried to do this from scratch, removing the users limitations and the "nasaccess" user works with ssh. With SFTP the error is changed: *subsystem request failed on channel 0
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer*. I'm also wondering what happens if using **ChrootDirectory** instead **internal-sftp**.

Comment: Oh, and when I'm entering with SSH, all the system folders are visible. Not what I need.

Comment: SOLVED using **sftp** as argument on **Subsystem**. That was not the name of the group. Whops.